# Launcher.QueryUriSupportAsync() - Not Working Windows 10 mobile

Tags: c#, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I am trying to find if the Facebook app is installed on a Windows 10 Mobile device so that authentication can be handled through the Facebook App instead of the `WebAuthenticationBroker`.

The following line of code always returns `LaunchQuerySupportStatus.NotSupported`

```
LaunchQuerySupportStatus uriAvailability = await Launcher.QueryUriSupportAsync(new Uri("fbconnect://authorize?client_id=.........", UriKind.Absolute), LaunchQuerySupportType.Uri);
```

If I bypass this check and go straight to `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync` then it opens the app as expected.  However, I need to perform the above check to support the desktop version, but it just doesn't give me any response back other than Not Supported.

Any thoughts???

**UDPATE**
I have been able to get `LaunchQuerySupportStatus.Available` when using my own app protocol `myapp://something/123/`.  I also found that I needed to add `UriKind.Absolute` in order for this to work.

However, still no change with the `fbconnect://` protocol

**UPDATE - 2**
I have now tried

```
var apps = await Launcher.FindUriSchemeHandlersAsync("fbconnect");
```

and still get no results.  If put the protocol of my own app in there, then I do get results.

Facebook is definitely installed if I miss this checking step then the launcher works and opens the Facebook app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of researching in more detail, it looks as though the problem with this is that the current Facebook app is built for Windows Phone 8, and was written in Silverlight.

When trying to perform the same action against Universal apps, both written by me, and by others, then both of the methods above work.

As I am writing for pre-release then I can only hope that Facebook have an official Windows 10 Mobile app shortly after the launch so that this works as I plan.

**UPDATE**
I have just heard back from Microsoft to say that this issue is fixed in an internal build, and should be available to the public soon.  Fingers crossed it will be in RTM for mobile.  I'll update this once I see the fix is available - The code shown in the original question will be correct.

Comment: I have created wp 8.1 project running in windows phone 10 device. `fbconnect` works fine in windows 8.1 device. But same is not working in windows 10. After log in from facebook app it doesnt redirect to my app instead its crashing. Any Idea? Is facebook not supporting single sign on?

Comment: Does you have any results?